# Any potential issues if I remove qmail accounts?

Tags: qmail

I have been using 13.10 only but after two weeks ago needed to install 12.04 to. With the default `guest` account I am getting other bunch of accounts as you can see:

[image]

I have used to disable guest account when installing 13.10 but have no idea what are these alias and qmail accounts for?

Other issue is that each time I try to update my 12.04 from the Update Manager or with `sudo apt-get install` I am getting errors like this:

```
The hostname -f command returned: $1

Your system needs to have a fully qualified domain name (fqdn) in
order to install the var-qmail packages.

Installation aborted.

dpkg: error processing qmail (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qmail-run:  qmail-run depends on qmail (>= 1.06-2.1); however:   Package qmail is not configured yet. dpkg: error processing qmail-run (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:  qmail  qmail-run E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Could you advice if it will be OK to disable these accounts and maybe try to delete this qmail stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps below to remove `qmail`:

1. sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove qmail-uids-gids
2. sudo apt-get purge qmail-uids-gids

You should see the following message:

```
Purging this package does not remove the qmail uids and gids.  You might want to do this manually, e.g.:

# userdel alias
# userdel qmaild
# userdel qmaill
# userdel qmailp
# userdel qmailq
# userdel qmailr
# userdel qmails
# groupdel qmail
# groupdel nofiles
```

Use `sudo userdel` and `sudo groupdel` to do the job:

```
sudo userdel alias
sudo userdel qmaild
sudo userdel qmaill
sudo userdel qmailp
sudo userdel qmailq
sudo userdel qmailr
sudo userdel qmails
sudo groupdel qmail
sudo groupdel nofiles
```

Answer (score 0):

These aliases are required for the proper functioning of qmail. Please see [lwq](http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#build) installation section for more info. And your FQDN issue is addressed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1950923)